# Get variable from parent class for use in method of child class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to understand how parent and child classes in Python work and I ran into this seemingly simple problem:

```
class parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 42


class child(parent):

    def __init__(self):
        self.string = 'is the answer!'

    def printDataAndString(self):
        print( str(self.data) + ' ' + self.string )


c = child()
c.printDataAndString()
```

I'm expecting the string *42 is the answer!* but I get

> AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute 'data'

**What am I missing?**

I experimentated with `pass` and also `super(parent,...)` but couldn't get it right.

Comment: FWIW, you _could_ call the parent `__init__` using `parent.__init__(self)`, but using `super` is preferred because it handle multiple inheritance properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your `child` has its own `__init__()` function, you need to call the parent class' `__init__()`  , otherwise it does not get called. Example -

```
def __init__(self):
    super(child,self).__init__()
    self.string = 'is the answer!'
```

[`super()` from documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) -

> **super(type[, object-or-type])**
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

So the first argument to `super()` should be the child class (whose' parent class' method you want to call) , and the second argument should be the object itself , that is self. Hence , `super(child, self)` .

In [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) , you can simply call -

```
super().__init__()
```

And it would call the `__init__()` method from the correct parent class.

Comment: What if the `_init_` function of my parent class contains a lot of variable declarations and some heavyweight file-io - is there are way to just get specific variables? Otherwise everytime I create an instance of my child class, it would call the `_init_` function of my parent class, which I guess would be a little overkill if I just need that one or two variables?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to define those one or two variables in the child class itself , and not call the `super().__init__()` .

Comment: @thewaywewalk: The simple answer is what Anand says: simply declare those variables in the child's `__init__` method and don't call the parent's  `__init__` method. However, if the child doesn't need all that extra stuff, then you should consider reorganizing the inheritance and swapping the roles of parent & child. The parent class ought to be the base class, with the child classes having the fancy added extras.